# dsadd gives "The name provided is not a properly formed account name."

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, command-line-interface

This command:

```
dsadd user "cn=testing dummy2,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local" -display "testing dummy2" -samid testing.dummy2@domain.local -pwd password76 -fn testing -ln dummy2 -disabled no -upn testing.dummy2@domain.local -desc testing -acctexpires 61 -mustchpwd yes
```

is returning this:

```
The name provided is not a properly formed account name. type dsadd /? for help
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be passing a UPN to the SAMAccountName property with the -samid switch. Get rid of the @ and everything after it for that switch.